# Angular ng-options display data from database

Tags: json, angularjs, html-select

> **EDIT** : The code its ok, the problem was `materialize` `select`, did not work with dynamic angular elements, use the class browser-default instead of input-field and do not inizializate with jquery.

Hello I'm trying to display data in a `select` tag with angular
I read a lot but I cannot solve this problem. As you can see with test code works but with the function does not. Need help. Thanks.

This is the JSON that PHP endpoint returns:

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "numero":"312312"
      },
      {
         "numero":"31221111"
      },
      {
         "numero":"311241"
      },
      {
         "numero":"112441"
      },
      {
         "numero":"11312"
      },
      {
         "numero":"131"
      }
   ]
}
```

Controller:

```
 app.controller('chequeoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   //with this function do not work
   $scope.leerNumero = function() {
     $http.get("objetos/autoelevador/leer_numero.php").success(function(response) {
       $scope.data = response.records;
       console.log($scope.data);
     });
   };
   $scope.leerNumero();

   // with this array works, just for test!!
   /*$scope.names = [{"name":"pepe"},{"name":"pepe2"}];
   console.log($scope.nombres); */
 })
```

My `select` tag:

```
<select  ng-model="autoelev" ng-options="item.numero as item.numero for item in data">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar autoelevador</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below, [**Demo here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MUSTHlzXknF6tTJYTxKK?p=preview):

**View:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-options="item.numero for item in data" ng-model="chosen">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar autoelevador</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json')
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.data = res.data.records;
        console.log($scope.data);
      });
  })
```

Do `$scope.data = response.data.records` in your controller and make sure its an array of options.

`console.log($scope.data)` in your controller should print as below:

```
[{"numero":"312312"},{"numero":"31221111"},{"numero":"311241"},{"numero":"112441"},{"numero":"11312"},{"numero":"131"}
```

Comment: it seems to be a problem with the data returned, i tried with a local function  with the same data and it works but with the get function doesnt, i dont know why, both arrays are the same when i do consle.log!

Comment: try `$scope.data = JSON.parse(response.data.records)`. your response could be string instead of JSON.

Comment: response.data.records i get  TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

and with JSON.parse(response.data.records) i get Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Object.parse (native)

btw with $scope.data = response.records; i can use ng-repeat normally the problem is just with ngOptions, its sems to be with external data problem, widh an array declared in the controller works fine

Comment: this is what console.log shows 

$scope.data = response.records;
console.log( $scope.data );[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
console.log($scope.data[3] ); Object {numero: "112441"}

Comment: If thats what the console.log shows, above code should work. I have already tested before posting the answer.

Comment: with $scope.data = response.records; just does not shows the option, no errors

Comment: please check this image i explain a bit better, read the comments   https://k60.kn3.net/25C5904DF.jpg

Comment: @Mars check the demo (edited answer) that I made and see what you're missing. https://plnkr.co/edit/MUSTHlzXknF6tTJYTxKK?p=preview

Comment: @Mars did it work ? If it did. Please accept the answer so that people will know this question is resolved.

Comment: no, not working :( maybe the problem is in the php file ill check that

Comment: @Mars damn, that really sucks. Good luck!

Comment: nope, is not a problem with php, it was an conflict with materialize i removed all materialize clases and now its working lol , thanks

Comment: damn dude, you need to improve skills to narrowing down the problem's cause. You got stuck for a day lol ! :D Congrats.

Comment: yeah a lot of time looking for a solution and the problem was materialize i cannot imagine that :( , and sorry for my english not my native languaje xD

Answer (score 0):

According to the $http docs your response object has a data property which stores your data (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

So you should use

```
$scope.data = response.data.records;
```

also the success function is deprecated. Please use

```
 $http.get("objetos/autoelevador/leer_numero.php").then(
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can select data from database using angularjs.**

```
// Application module
var App = angular.module('myApp',[]);
App.controller("DbController",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

// Function to get details from the database
getInfo();
function getInfo(){
// Sending request to sample.php files
$http.post('databaseFiles/sample.php').success(function(data){
// Stored the returned data into scope
$scope.details = data;
});
}
```

**Details.php.**

```
<?php
// Including database connections
require_once 'database_connections.php';
// mysqli query to fetch all data from database
$query = "   ";//write your select query
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$arr[] = $row;
}
}
// Return json array containing data from the databasecon
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);
?>
```